# Java's DAO definition of Factory Method

Tags: java, hibernate, design-patterns, factory

I was reading today, again after many years, the article [**Core J2EE Patterns - Data Access Object**](https://www.oracle.com/technetwork/java/dataaccessobject-138824.html) and came across these two definitions of DAO implementations, the first one using Factory Method and the second one using Abstract Factory. Although the article claims the first example to be using factory method, I've started to think that it could just as well be defined as an abstract factory with a single concrete factory implementation.

**Example Factory method:**

[image: factory method]

**Example Abstract Factory:**

[image: abstract factory]

Going back to GoF, we can find arguments as to why it is an abstract factory:

- Abstract factory creates a factory of related products, which would be the single concrete implementation of the first example.
- Abstract factory is used, among other things, to create gui toolkit factories for different look and feels that would return different components to be worked on by other classes. These components are closely related. These would be the concrete dao factory implementation itself, which has methods for creating the individual products/daos.

I have also seen many discussions explaining the difference between inheritance (factory method) and composition (abstract factory) but I think that distinction is very ambiguous. In GoF we read that one of the two ways to use factory methods is to `Connects parallel class hierarchies` which means allowing classes other than the creator (class that implements the factory method) to call these factory methods.

If some class is calling a factory method from another class, using the interface exported by a `creator`, that is the same thing as calling a method from an `abstract factory`. Both examples use inheritance to benefit from the polymorfism and both are creating concrete produtcts, based on some abstract product interface. In essence, that means the same UML diagram could describe both patterns.

So in the end, I think it all comes down to whether I'm defining/describing `DAOFactory` as a creator with multiple factory operations, in the case of factory method or an abstract factory in the case of an abstract factory, which have the following definitions in GoF:

> **creator** (Factory Method)
>
> - declares the factory method, which returns an object of type Product. Creator may also define a default implementation of the
>   factory method that returns a default ConcreteProduct object.
> - may call the factory method to create a Product object.
>
> **abstract factory** (Abstract Factory)
>
> - declares an interface for operations that create abstract product
>   objects

Reading further it even seems as if the author thinks Abstract Factory is an abstract method with a switch case selecting a factory method to be returned, as in a "factory of factories". This becomes clear with the following excerpts:

> This strategy uses the Factory Method implementation in the factories
> produced by the Abstract Factory. ... The Factory for Data Access
> Objects Strategy uses the Factory Method pattern to implement the
> concrete factories and its products (DAOs). For added flexibility, the
> Abstract Factory pattern may be employed as discussed in the
> strategies.

Abstract factories don't "produce" factories. Abstract factories are just interfaces describing operations that create products. The article goes on to show a sample code with an abstract method creating factory methods inside a switch case. Saying Abstract Factories produce something just sounds wrong to me.

So to decide whether the pattern is a factory method or an abstract factory, I need more than just the UML, but the requirement of the application to define what pattern best fits the description of the requirement. And so when I did that, it sounded like abstract factory fit better both examples from Oracle.

First because all DAOs are tightly coupled. I could share the same connection between them right from inside DaoFactory or even share a transaction. Second because there are multiple methods and I access them from a centralized object. Factory method in and of itself sounds more like a lone wolf in a creator class. When you have many of them you start stepping more into an abstract factory definition, sorta. Even though GoF has the example of the MazeGame defining many factory methods, MazeGame is never considered a factory. It either creates a maze using many factory methods or using an abstract factory.

I don't think calling the first example factory method just because there was only one implementation is justification enough nor is it calling the second example abstract factory just because it produces a factory method.

Have I missed something? Is my view of both patterns up to date or has it changed since GoF?

Comment: Your question is not likely to get a clear answer. Can you provide more details about the specific application? It sounds like your question is about which pattern to use in your case, but there are not enough details.

Comment: My question is about the definition the book J2EE Patterns gave to the two implementations/diagrams above. They explain the abstract factory as being a factory of factories and the factory method as being a class full of creator methods. I just wanted other people's opinions about this before criticising that book's example.

Comment: [1] @DaniloSouzaMorães While you have obviously put a lot of effort into your question, it is clearly inviting subjective and opinion based answers, and is therefore [off topic for Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/help/dont-ask). [2] Perhaps take a look at [StackExchange's Software Engineering site](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help)  to review whether your question might be more appropriate there.